# Move Item to front of list when using for in loop

Tags: python, list

What would be the most pythonic way to move an item to the front of a list, when iterate through the list with a `for in` loop?

As such:

```
for item in items:
    if condition:
        # Move `item` to front of `items`
        break
```

Comment: To clarify add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a list while iterating over it, is generally not recommended, that said:

```
>>> ctr = 0
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> for i in lst:
...:     if ctr == 3:
...:         lst.insert(0,lst.pop(ctr))
...:         break
...:     ctr += 1
...:
>>> lst
[4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Or,

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> for i,x in enumerate(lst):
...     if x == 3:
...         lst.insert(0,lst.pop(i))
...         break
>>> lst
[3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Would It be ok to do that if I intend to break the loop after the condition is met?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be least error-prone to do things the "manual" way:

```py
new_items = []
for item in items:
    if condition:
        new_items.insert(0, item)  # Prepend
    else:
        new_items.append(item)  # Append
# if you need to modify `items` "in-place", assign to a slice:
items[:] = new_items
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to something like this:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(items):
   if 'condition on item':
      items.pop(idx)
      items.insert(0, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a number we are talking about numbers. In our example, our condition is if number is larger than 2, put it in front of the list else append.

```
items = [5, 3, -2, 3, 1,]

new_list = []

for item in items:
    if item > 2:
        new_list.insert(0, item)
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

What this will print out in our new_list.

```
[3, 3, 5, -2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the slicing technique only:

```py
data = list(range(10))

for i, j in enumerate(data):
    if i == 5:
        # shift all numbers left of j one position to the right
        l[1:i+1] = l[:i]
        l[0] = j
        break
```

Gives the following result:

```
>>> data
[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```